# Compare strings using pointers?

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm an informatic student (University) and i'm studying C lenguage right now.
I'm trying to do some exercises about pointers and strings. I found ad exercise with a particular function, that help to compare 2 strings using pointers. 
The solution of the Function is:

```
int compare_strings( char *a, char *b){
  int i = 0;

  while( *( a + i ) != '\0' && *( b + i ) != '\0' ){
    if( *( a + i ) < *( b + i ) ){
      return -1;
    } else if( *( a + i ) > *( b + i ) ){
      return 1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if( *( a + i ) == '\0' && *( b + i ) == '\0' ){
    return 0;
  } else if( ( a + i ) != '\0' ){
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

I really dont get the sense of this function. How can an alphabetic character be "more" then another aphabetic character? What it means?
Or simply it's uncorrect?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't know if it matters for you or not, but notice that `*(a+i)` is stricly equivalent to `a[i]` in `C`, so the function you found add complicated things where there shouldn't be.

Comment: Characters have an order. They're stored as numbers and those internal  "codes" are what's compared (see ASCII). It's sort of like alpha order.

Comment: @Holt i know this, and thank you for refresh my mind with this tips ^^ But the exercise is on pointers and char, so i have to do it without using array :/

Comment: Note: could change `while() {...}` to `while( *( a + i ) != '\0' &&  *( a + i ) == *( b + i ) ){ i++; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each character has its internal representation according to some coding scheme.  For example character 'A' in ASCII is stored as value 65, 'B' - as 66 and so on. So when you compare characters their internal codes are compared.

All is a digit inside the computer.:) And there are two such digits: 0 and 1. All other numbers and symbols (from the human point of view) are formed from these two digits.

That it would be more clear try the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c;

    for ( c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c )
    {
        printf( "%d ", (int )c );
    }

    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

Take into account that when characters are used as operands of relation operators they are implicitly converted to type int as in my program where I convert them to int explicitly.

Comment: And if i compare (i can do with this program) two words like "hello" and "words", the program tell me that words its > than hello because of the ascii code of the W?

Comment: @Sylvestol You are right. The internal code of w is greater than internal code of h because w follows h.

Answer (score 1):

In C, as in most languages, `char` are simply integer, which are converted using some kinds of table ([ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table for example, or `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, etc.). In ASCII, you have for example `'A' = 0x41` or `'a' = 0x61` (same value in `UTF-8` because `UTF-8` only extends ASCII table without modifying it). Comparing `char` is only comparing what is called their ASCII values (even if the coding system is not always ASCII values).

In most (not all, see chux comment bellow) encoding systems, integer value beyond `char` keep the alphabetical order and place uppercase letter at a lower place that lowercase letter, so `'A' < 'a'` and `' ' < 'A'` or even `'0' < 'A'`.

When you compare string, you compare all their letters and in fact return the result of the first different characters, as you would do in a dictionnary (`hello` is before `manual` which is before `table`).

Comment: @chux Of course it was! It's always good to learn new things even when answering to someone on SO!

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is really just a 1 byte number that the system interprets as a character using a format (I believe it's ASCII but I could be very wrong so someone please correct me if it's not the case). For example in ASCII:

a is 97, b is 98

A is 65, B is 66

etc

So you can say that 'a' < 'b' and 'A' < 'a' which puts things in alphabetical order.